# SFSB being removed

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x, codi

I'm using JBoss6.1.Final, JSF 2.0 (Mojarra), Weld CDI, MyFaces CODI 1.0.5 (for view-access-scoped)

I'm using something like the Gateway Pattern from [Real World Java EE Patterns Rethinking Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0557078326) (unfortunately I don't have it with me, so I may have screwed something up here).  Basically, the application allows a user to go into "edit mode" and edit a List of people (create, edit, remove) maintained in a @ViewAccessScoped backing bean with an extended persistence context and then click a "save" command link that flushes all their changes to the database.  At first I was having a problem with ViewExpiredExceptions (if the browser was idle past the session-timeout period and then further requests are performed), but I added some jQuery to make a get request to a servlet that keeps the session alive (called 10 seconds before session-timeout).  This seems to be working but now I have another problem, the backing bean is also a SFSB and after some idle time, it is being removed resulting in the following error message being logged (and all ajax rendered data disappears) when I attempt to perform more edits ...

13:06:22,063 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @27,81 rendered="#{!conversationBean.editMode}": javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Could not find stateful bean: 43h1h2f-9c7qkb-h34t0f34-1-h34teo9p-de

Any ideas on how I could prevent SFSB removal or at least handle it more gracefully?

Here's my backing bean:

```
package com.ray.named;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;

import com.ray.model.Person;

@Named
@Stateful
@ViewAccessScoped
@TransactionAttribute(javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class ConversationBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  //properties
  private List<Person> people;
  private String name;
  private Boolean editMode;

  @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  private EntityManager em;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    people = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll", Person.class).getResultList();
    setEditMode(false);
  }

  //event listeners
  public void beginEdits() {
    setEditMode(true);
  }

  public void addPerson() {
    Person p = new Person(name);
    em.persist(p);
    people.add(p);
    name = null;
  }

  public void removePerson(Person p) {
    people.remove(people.indexOf(p));
    em.remove(p);
  }

  //this method flushes the persistence context to the database
  @TransactionAttribute(javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void saveEdits() {
    setEditMode(false);
  }

  //getters/setters
  public List<Person> getPeople() {
    return people;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Boolean getEditMode() {
    return editMode;
  }

  public void setEditMode(Boolean editMode) {
    this.editMode = editMode;
  }
}
```

Here's the Person entity bean:

```
package com.ray.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll",
              query="SELECT p FROM Person p")
})
public class Person {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  @Version
  private int version;

  public Person() { }

  public Person(String name) {
    setName(name);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Person)) {
      return false;
    }
    return id == ((Person)o).id;
  }

  //getters/setters
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public int getVersion() {
    return version;
  }

  public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
  }
}
```

Here's the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.get("#{request.contextPath}/poll");
    }, #{(session.maxInactiveInterval - 10) * 1000});
  });
  </script>
  <title>Conversation Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Begin Edits" rendered="#{!conversationBean.editMode}">
      <f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{conversationBean.beginEdits}"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink value="Save" rendered="#{conversationBean.editMode}">
      <f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{conversationBean.saveEdits}"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:dataTable id="peopleTable" value="#{conversationBean.people}" var="person">
      <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
        <h:panelGroup>
          <h:inputText value="#{person.name}" disabled="#{!conversationBean.editMode}">
            <f:ajax/>
          </h:inputText>
          <h:commandLink value="X" disabled="#{!conversationBean.editMode}">
            <f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{conversationBean.removePerson(person)}"/>
          </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:outputLabel for="name">Name:</h:outputLabel>
      <h:inputText id="name" value="#{conversationBean.name}" disabled="#{!conversationBean.editMode}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Add" disabled="#{!conversationBean.editMode}">
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{conversationBean.addPerson}"/>
    </h:commandButton>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here's a servlet used to keep the session alive (called by jQuery ajax get request 10 seconds before session expires):

```
package com.ray.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class PollServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public void init() throws ServletException {
  }

  public String getServletInfo() {
    return null;
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.getSession(); //Keep session alive
  }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas on how I could prevent SFSB removal or at least handle it
>   more gracefully?

To investigate further I would recommend to take a look at the EJB lifecycle hooks for **passivation** and add some debug output there.

Should that be the source of the problem you will be able to configure / deactivate passivation - but scalability might come up as an issue.

Honestly, this scenario seems quite uncommon to me. In general I would expect requests / conversations / sessions to be working more or less in the default boundaries - should you find yourself writing code that circumvents this can it be that you are better off with a RESTful / stateless approach...?

Please update the question with further information if available.

Comment: Thanks yet again Jan. Just curious, do you see anything flawed with my example code?  Is there anything that you would do differently?

Comment: I added a @PrePassivate annotated method and could see that the backing/session bean was indeed being passivated. I'm experimenting with RichFaces a4j:poll with an interval of 10 seconds less than the session.maxInactiveInterval and this seems to be doing the trick. The session stays alive as long as the browser window is open.

Comment: @Jasonl(#1) No, there is nothing wrong with your code. I cant express myself any better as I already did in the answer...

Comment: Thank you Jan. Your help has been tremendous!

Comment: You're welcome - should you want to discuss your architecture from a more general point of view you might want to open a new question where you give more information about your application...

Comment: btw, you don't need the polling mechanisms. You can configure your session timeout in your web.xml and you can change your passivation interval in your application server console/config. Alternatively, it would be a good idea to implement passivation for your beans should scalability become an issue, or just let the session expire and ask the user to start over, depending on the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had no idea that EJBs are still a thing... :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already solved your problem. Otherwise, this JBoss wiki page should be helpful (also for future readers...).

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Ejb3DisableSfsbPassivation

Cheers,
Luigi